# What is a preferred/efficient way to send hundreds or thousands of http requests (c#)?

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, task

In my scenario, I need to process a list of items (pseudo code is blow) , the number of which could be hundreds or thousands. So, what is an efficient way to handle this? Are there some patterns/best practices for this kind of scenario?

Some specific questions are:

1. I think I should change the sync call on **QueryResultAsync** to async first, but Micrsoft doc doesn't recommend to use async/await in a tight loop. So, any walkaround?
2. Should I consider using multiple tasks concurrently running at the same time to reduce latency? e.g., say there are 100 items to process, and I create 10 tasks (one for each item) running at the same time and WaitAll() of them and then there will be 10 rounds to finish the 100 items. Is this better?
3. Should I consider producer/consumer pattern, where 3 producers for web requests and one consumer to handle the results?

Please let me know if your (scenario) info needed.

```
    public List<string> Process(List<string> items) 
    {
       List<string> resultItems = new List<string>(items.Count);
       foreach (string item in items)
       {
          string result = QueryResultAsync(item).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // need to send http request for each item with different urls
          resultItems.Add(ProcessResult(result);
       }
       
       return resultItems;
    }

    private static string ProcessResult(string item){
        // some plain processing logic without I/O
        return result; // a string value
    }
```

Comment: "Micrsoft doc doesn't recommend to use async/await in a tight loop" - where is this doc?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async, and  search "Consider using ValueTask where possible" section.

Comment: @zjg.robin, that's not saying the "doesn't recommend to use async/await in a tight loop". That's a general comment on allocations on performance critical tight loops. And the recommendation is not to use async, but to use `ValueTask` instead of `Task`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are IO bound workloads, you could simply use the *async and await pattern*, and `Task.WhenAll` and let the task scheduler deal with the details

```
public async Task<List<string>> Process(List<string> items)
{
   var tasks = items.Select(x => QueryResultAsync(x));
   var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   return results.Select(x => ProcessResult(x)).ToList();
}
```

If you are interesting in multiple producers you could use *Tpl Dataflow pipeline* which can better partition and deal with max concurrent requests, then pipe your results in to the processor.

A nonsensical example

```
// create some blocks
var queryBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(
   QueryResultAsync,
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
   {
      EnsureOrdered = false,
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 // ??
   });

var processBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(
   ProcessResult,
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
   {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, // ??
   });

var someOtherAction = new ActionBlock<string>(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

//link them together
queryBlock.LinkTo(processBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() {PropagateCompletion = true});
processBlock.LinkTo(someOtherAction, new DataflowLinkOptions() {PropagateCompletion = true});

// produce some junk
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   await queryBlock.SendAsync(i.ToString());

// wait for it all to finish
queryBlock.Complete();
await someOtherAction.Completion;
```

**Output**

```
0
8
7
1
2
5
6
3
4
9
```

There are many ways you can config a pipeline and they have many options, this is just an example

Comment: for the simple way of letting default task scheduler all these tasks, I am concerning whether it could consume all thread resources if the number of items is large. And our service runs on a very resource sensitive machine where there are a lot of other services running at the same time.

Comment: @zjg.robin https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html